# Change resolution of image in WIndows 8 Store App

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-store-apps

I have created a windows store app. I want to resize a image size, code below is to save the image:

```
private async void saveImage(StorageFile destinationFile)
{
     if (destinationFile != null)
     {
         using (var readStream = await sourceFile.OpenReadAsync())
         {
               var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(readStream);
               using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream writeStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
               {
                    BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(writeStream, decoder);
                    encoder.BitmapTransform.Bounds = new BitmapBounds()
                    {
                         X = (uint)Math.Round(selectedLeft, 0),
                         Y = (uint)Math.Round(selectedTop, 0),
                         Width = (uint)Math.Round(selectedWidth, 0),
                         Height = (uint)Math.Round(selectedHeight, 0),
                    };
                    await encoder.FlushAsync();
                    using (var stream = await destinationFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                    {
                         await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(writeStream.GetInputStreamAt(0), stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
                    }
               }
       }
}
```

The saved image size is 320x480. How to I resize to 960x1240? Thanks

Comment: Your target aspect ratio doesn't match your source - Your X scale is 3, but your Y is 2.58 (roughly) - Did you mean that?

Comment: No, the ratio is not important, any size also can. What I need is just can change to specific size.